# Two parallel commands with on ODBCConnection (C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading, odbc

I have two threads. Each thread executes a command. The same ODBCConnection object is passed to both threads. Will a command from the second thread wait for the command from the first thread to complete if the ODBCConnection object is the same?

Exactly what i want to know can i use one odbcconnection object to excute parallel comands in the same time?

Comment: Have a look here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/synchronization-of-an-odbc-connection

Comment: Thanx, but i want to know can i use one ODBCConnection object to excute two commands in parallel thread in tha same time?

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer? "The OdbcConnection is not thread-safe in any way". So: no

Comment: I read this article. Not thread-safe means there will be a deadlock?

Comment: It just means that it is not safe to use from multiple threads. The result may be a deadlock, a crash, or just a wrong result.